# Why do I get a “Connection to [host] closed by remote host” error over SFTP connection?

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I'd like to connect as `user` to a remote host through SFTP.

Moreover, I'd like to land into a specific directory (say `/home/user/dir`). I've created user with default working directory as `/home/user/dir`and set a `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_key` file to host my public key.

However, upon connexion using `sftp -P 7000 user@host.com` and after typing `user`'s password, I get the following error immediatly: `Connection to host.com closed by remote host. Connection closed.`

Any idea about where it might come from (or how to debug that kind of issue)?

**UPDATE**

I was finally to connect as `user` because `authorized_key` didn't have the proper rights. However, I got the exact same error message while trying to land in `/home/user/dir` with another user (say `user2`) which was granted group access to `/home/user/dir`. But as it turn out in this [response](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359523/restrict-sftp-user-to-multiple-folders/359554), SFTP chroot jail does not allow that by design. I'll try to use symbolic links between `/home/user/dir` and `/home/user2/dir` to solve this issue.

Comment: First add `-vvv`: `sftp -P 7000 user@host.com -vvv` and show output

Comment: I get the exact same output : `Connection to host.com closed by remote host. Connection closed.`

Comment: Did you set /home/user/dir as your user's $HOME ? or what else did you do to "land into a specific directory" ? Did logging in work before you changed that directory?

Comment: Sorry, my fault: `sftp -P 7000 -vvv user@host.com`

Comment: @hyph I defined `user` default directory using `usermod -m -d /home/user/dir user` @Tomasz Jakub Rup The log is quite extensive : https://pastebin.com/0dRZBPUS

Comment: Please show Your `.bashrc` file (from `host.com`)

Comment: so then you put your dotfiles and folders in /home/user/dir not in /home/user and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

**How to debug**

First step is running command with verbose flag:

```
sftp -P 7000 -vvv user@host.com
```

**Analyze of log**

Connection are estabilished

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

but, `ssh` cannot set non-blocking mode:

```
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Connection to host.com closed by remote host.
```

Probably Your shell initialization file (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, etc.) breaking ssh connection

Comment: I get the fd 1 is not 0_NONBLOCK what is wrong with my .zshrc? I don't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

I was stumbling on this question when I had a similar issue, I followed [this](https://qiita.com/alokrawat050/items/709d3c777407ab658aa9)
guide and that worked for me.
In essence using user's home directories will not work since the directory that you want to lock the user to must be owned by root and cannot be writable by anyone else.

So try to:

- create a folder like `/var/sftp` that is owned by root
- add a sub-folder like `/var/sftp/user1` that is owned by user1 and where they can write to
- then modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` like following, so that the user can only access their folder for file access/upload

  ```
    Match User user1
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    ChrootDirectory /var/sftp
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
  ```
- finally restart ssh service `sudo systemctl restart sshd`
- access to other user's folders can be restricted by `sudo chmod 700 /var/sftp/*`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on a chroot SSH login.  I solved it by increasing log level in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
LogLevel VERBOSE
```

Then I restarted `sshd` and watched the log file while connection attempts were being made:

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
tail -f /var/log/auth.log
```

It turned out to be a permissions issue on the directory:

```
May 13 09:13:41 myserver sshd[12216]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/home/remote/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your config `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and change the `PasswordAuthentication` from **no** to **yes**

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).